# Android OnClick Listview item Animation

Tags: android, listview, animation, onclick

[image]
Android List view animation in OnClick item

I want this type of animation onClick of Listview item..in Android.. Can anybody help me ?? Please...

Comment: means need to animation which is display as a circle in screen?

Comment: Yes.. i need to that type of animation in OnClick of listview's item...

Comment: so have you done animation??

Comment: Yaa..i have this type of animation but whenever i implement, it goes to force close...

Comment: means what type of error it shows to you..??

Comment: IF it is shows null pointer exception error?

Comment: Fatel error.. i just need to create this type of custom view in each of list iem.. just i click on list view item, immediatly goes to force close..

Comment: you have to create only one view and just animate it accroding to click event of list item..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks similar to the [Satellite menu](https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu). You could use the library in the link.

Comment: Yeah...Nice... But how can i Implement in OnClick of Listview Item ?? i need to put this animation in my list view's item...

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with that because I haven't used it in a list view yet. I presume that you would have to add the menu image to your custom list view layout so that the menu item could appear.